# Recyclerview растягивается

Tags: java, android, recyclerview

Такая проблема, не могу понять с чем связана, при пролистывании списка фрейм становиться на весь экран

[image: 1][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Добавьте XML к вопросу, мне кажется дело в нем.

Answer (score 1):

Да, действительно проблема была в xml, xml содержал `RelativeLayout`, который содержал `TextView`. 

Добавил `CardView` и в него уже внес `RelativeLayout`вместе с `TextView`